What is the alternate of AxisHTTPSessionListener?
I am using AxisHTTPSessionListener in my web.xml as listener like below.
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisHTTPSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

Now I am upgrading JDK version 11 to 17 and part of it upgrading javax to jakarta.
Issue is AxisHTTPSessionListener internally using the javax.
package org.apache.axis.transport.http;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import javax.xml.rpc.server.ServiceLifecycle;
import org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

public class AxisHTTPSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

So I am getting below error
Error configuring application listener of class [org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisHTTPSessionListener] ([/test].log)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener


How to resolve it?

This is caused by the upgrade of Tomcat rather than the upgrade of the jdk.
See Tomcat Migration 10

There is a significant breaking change between Tomcat 9.0.x and Tomcat 10.0.x. The Java package used by the specification APIs has changed from javax... to jakarta.... It will be necessary to recompile web applications against the new APIs.

I think you'll need a version of axis which is compiled against jakarta instead of javax
I see there is this ticket asking for jakarta support in axis
You could possibly use tool that supports package relocation such as Shadow to produce a new/hacked axis jar pointing to the jakarta servlet classes (assuming it's just a package relocation and no logic changes required)
Another option is to grab the axis sources and make the changes there

I am trying to find axis version which using jakarta, but not able to find it. In axis2 I am not able to find the AxisHTTPSessionListener.

See my comments, there's an open issue
